# Ionic and Angular on Cousera

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been following a coursera tutorial, but I have an error.

I have the teacher's code but it doesn't work

Sorry I do not put code, but I do not know what code to put since everything marks well

attached images and link of bitbucket where is my current code

In advance thanks for the help

[image]

[image]

[image]

bitbucket link: **https://bitbucket.org/pablolira/confusion-ionic/src/master/**

PD: 
These are the versions I am using:

- node@8.11.3
- @angular/cli@8.3.18
- cordova@9.0.0
- ionic@3.20.1
- json-server@0.15.1
- typescript@3.7.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219099/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-ionic-3 (perhaps? I Googled on "error module parse failed unexpected token (55:0) ionic 3")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you've forgotten to add a module file for the home page. All page files will need a `pageName.module.ts` file where you setup the declarations, imports, exports, etc. for the page. What your home folder looks like:

[image]

what it should look like (example from your about page folder):
[image]

You should be able to copy the contents from `about.module.ts` and paste into a new file `home.module.ts`, replacing references to the About Page with references to the Home Page.

You can also avoid this going forward if you use the Ionic CLI to generate pages like so:

`ionic generate page home`

or [checkout the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate) for more options on generating pages, components, directives, and services that come with the necessary boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of @Cortney Thomas and it worked

Thanks a lot